# Can I use anvils in Minecraft to give items colorful names?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing on a Minecraft server and a guy just started to give away his own items with colorful names.
Can I use anvils to give colorful names to items?

Answer (score 1):

Use § mark. You can use §0-§9 and also §{letter}.
§0text = black text, §1text = blue text, etc.

Minecraft wikipedia: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes